# Selenium Java Chrome Session Not Created Exception

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

TestNG Version 6.13.1

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.544337 (8c0344a12e552148c185f7d5117db1f28d6c9e85) on port 47944
Only local connections are allowed.
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
Session Not Created Excpetion:session not created exception
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544337 (8c0344a12e552148c185f7d5117db1f28d6c9e85),
platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 571 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0'
```

Using Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
 <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code is:

```
Public class Trans extends Base{
   @BeforeTest
   public void setup()throws IOException{
   driver = globalDriver();
```

GlobalDriver is called from Base which is:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Update the question with your _code trial_ and _error stack trace_

Comment: it's mostly  because of maven dependency , how have you declared the dependency ?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: With no additional info, I would assume it's a most popular reason - driver/browser compatibility issue, see: [WebDriverError: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807596/webdrivererror-disconnected-unable-to-connect-to-renderer)

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Here was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770943/selenium-chromedriver-session-not-created-unable-to-connect-to-renderer